# Weird border on Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, border

I have the following table in HTML

```
<table class="print-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left" colspan="2">1</td>
      <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left">4</td>
      <td class="border-top border-bottom border-right">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right" colspan="2">6</td>
      <td colspan="2">9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the css as follow

```
.print-table {
    width: 700px;
    /*border-spacing: 0;*/
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

    .print-table td {
        padding: 2px;
    }

.border-top {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.border-left {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.border-right {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

On Chrome 33.0.1750.146 m, it's showing like this
[image]
The top border of cell 6 shouldn't be there

On firefox 27 and IE 11, both are rendering correctly
[image]

Is this a bug of Chrome? please help
http://plnkr.co/edit/DHQFLmkWrQfl7tYqJZJl?p=preview

**UPDATE**
The issue is border conflict and is documented here
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of different interpretations of the collapsing border model in browsers. Issue happens when you use colspan along with collapse.

One way is to not use collapse, another is to remove colspan. See the second way html here. I removed the colspan from second row.

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/KVcLG/

```
<table class="print-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left" colspan="2">1</td>
      <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left">4</td>
      <td class="border-top border-bottom border-right">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right" colspan="2">6</td>
      <td colspan="2">9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your problem is as follows:

```
.print-table {
border-spacing: 0;
/* border-collapse: collapse; */
}
```

Remove or comment out `border-collapse: collapse;` from the `.print-table`

Comment: i do need them collapsed

Answer (score 0):

From what i've tested your .print_table class has a border-collapse: collapse property which also exists in the bootstrap. I suggest to change this from border-collapse: collapse to border-collapse: inherit

```
.print-table {
    width: 700px;
    /*border-spacing: 0;*/
    border-collapse: inherit;
}
```

Comment: I am not using bootstrap